# Html web app : how to prevent ios keyboard to be shown above the page

Tags: android, html, ios, css

I've been searching for hours but haven't found anything.

I have a web app with a sticky button at the bottom of the page.

When I focus the input, it's working perfectly great on android as the keyboard pushes the page.

But on ios, the keyboard is coming above the page which cause the button to be hidden by the keyboard. It's my main call to action, I don't want it hidden :P

Is there any work around to get the same effect as android do on ios ?

codepen: https://codepen.io/Pixelize/pen/rRKRBm

```css
body, html { margin: 0; min-height: 100vh; display: flex;
flex-direction: column;}
.container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  flex: 1;
}

.btn button {
  background: blue; width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>TITLE</div>
  <input type="text">
  <div class="btn">
    <button>SIGN IN</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

For example, here are two gifs:

ios: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s95at.gif

android: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yjOB.gif

Comment: Share us the button's css

Comment: done + codepen ;)